# Nginx reverse proxy Serving Node.js app static file

Tags: node.js, nginx, vue.js, single-page-application, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Laravel application in which one route /onlineAds will take me to another application (an SPA one) built with Vue.Js as front and Node.js as Back. So I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy in order to serve my SpaApp's static files but without any success.

My conf is as follow:

```
/                   =>      will be serverd from "C:/laragon/www/laravel_App/public/"
/onlineAds/(*)      =>      will be serverd from "C:/laragon/www/VueNodeApp/dist/"
/api/(*)            =>      will be proxied to nodeJs server
```

Here is what I tried to do with Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name domain.test *.domain.test;
  root "C:/laragon/www/laravel_App/public/";

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
      autoindex on;
  }

  location ~* ^\/onlineAds(.*)$ {
      alias "C:/laragon/www/craiglist/dist/";
      #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~* ^\/api(.*)$ {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_read_timeout      300;
      proxy_pass              http://localhost:8081;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass php_upstream;        
      #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }


  charset utf-8;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that for this configuration. it seems that laravel routing system catchs the /onlineAds and gives me a 404 error

Comment: You will get a 404 because your `alias` statement is wrong. An `alias` inside a *regular expression* `location` requires the full path to the file. Try: `C:/laragon/www/craiglist/dist$1;`

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith, your suggestion has worked and now /onlineAds does give me the correct index file but the CSS and JS file do not load and givesme a 404. Any idea why?

Comment: You will see the GET requests for the CSS and JS files in the Nginx access log. That should tell you why Nginx cannot find the files.

Comment: I think that it tries to get the asset files from laravel's public folder and not from vue's dist folder!!
`"GET /onlineAds/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-"
"GET /css/app.9a1eae5e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 16216 "http://domain.test:8080/onlineAds/"
"GET /js/app.1f025f79.js HTTP/1.1" 404 16216 "http://domain.test:8080/onlineAds/"
"GET /js/about.d4a2497d.js HTTP/1.1" 404 18366 "http://domain.test:8080/onlineAds/"
`

Comment: Either you need to fix the app under `/onlineAds/` to request its resources from the correct URI or you need to get Nginx to look for JS and CSS files in two places.

Comment: Any idea on how to always serve the index.html of vueApp for /onlineAds/*?

Comment: I don't understand - you already stated that "/onlineAds does give [you] the correct index file".

Comment: indeed, but /onlineAds/toto for example gives me a 404. since my app is a SPA /onlineAds/* should serve me the index.html which is not the case for this configuration

Comment: Also adding a try_files below the alias does not work. it seem that there is a bug when using try_files+alias

Comment: Within the `location` instead of `try_files` after the `alias` try: `if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /onlineAds/index.html last; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks alot, you've really been a big help. i really appreciate it alot. that worked well :D
Sorry to keep bothering you but i'm still getting the 404 for the assets. can you please enlighten me on how to get Nginx to look for JS and CSS files in two places. i'm really a total novice in nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `alias` statement within a *regular expression* `location` requires the full path to the file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ~* ^\/onlineAds(.*)$ {
    alias "C:/laragon/www/craiglist/dist$1";
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /onlineAds/index.html last; }
}
```

The use of `try_files` with `alias` is avoided due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

Assuming that the URI `/js/foo.js` could be located in `C:/laragon/www/laravel_App/public/js/foo.js` or `C:/laragon/www/craiglist/dist/js/foo.js`, you could ask Nginx to try both locations using `try_files` with a common `root` directory.

For example:

```
location /js/ {
    root "C:/laragon/www";
    try_files /laravel_App/public$uri /craiglist/dist$uri =404;
}
location /css/ {
    root "C:/laragon/www";
    try_files /laravel_App/public$uri /craiglist/dist$uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :D